# DateTime to int (по мск)

Tags: c#, .net

DateTime.Now выводит текущее московское время, но почему при переводе DateTime.Now в int

```
(int)(DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds
```

И затем обратно в DateTime получается уже не Московское время, а время на три часа позже

Comment: А что получается? Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Как именно вы переводите время обратно в DateTime?

Comment: Понятно, что вы получаете время на три часа позже (UTC), непонятно, как именно. добавьте код получения DateTime из секунд :)

Comment: В unix time конвертере

Comment: Этот Unix Time конвертер скорее всего создает время в UTC таймзоне. Т.е. это тот же момент времени, просто отображается он так, как его видят где-то в Англии :)

Comment: Нет, он отображает таким образом ```GMT: Mon, 04 Nov 2019 13:14:05 GMT
Ваша временная зона: 04.11.2019, 16:14:05``` причем моя временная зона на 3 часа позже

Comment: А как получить тогда на три часа раньше, Московское время?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы проверяете значение в Unix Time конвертере.

Unix Time - это количество секунд, прошедших с 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Проблема в том, что [оператор вычитания для DateTime не учитывает свойство Kind и таймзону вообще](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_subtraction?view=netframework-4.8). Перед его использованием нужно явно приводить оба аргумента к одной таймзоне, иначе результат поплывет:

> The Subtraction(DateTime, DateTime) method does not consider the value of the Kind property of the two DateTime values when performing the subtraction. Before subtracting DateTime objects, ensure that the objects represent times in the same time zone. Otherwise, **the result will include the difference between time zones**.

Вот этот difference в 3 часа вы и видите.

Вам нужно или использовать время в UTC при вычислении:

```
(int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds;
```

В случае не Now:

```
(int)(somedatetime.ToUniversalTime() - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds;
```